# Obtendo texto dentro de outro texto

Tags: c#, .net, string, regex, visual-basic-6

Quero obter uma `List(Of String)` de blocos de texto, porém há um problema:

```
{ --isso é um bloco;
  echo "Aqui tem um } no meio";}
```

e gostaria de obter desse jeito:

```
--isso é um bloco;
echo "Aqui tem um } no meio";
```

porém ta voltando assim no meu método:

```
--isso é um bloco;
echo "Aqui tem um
```

e simplesmente para ali, tem algum jeito então de obter **vários blocos** exceto quando estão dentro dos caracteres `"..."`?

Aqui está meu código do método:

```
Dim tmpBlocks() As String = theFile.Split({"{"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
Dim Blocks As New List(Of String)

For i As Integer = 0 To tmpBlocks.Length - 1
    Blocks.Add(tmpBlocks(i).Split(New [String]() {"}"}, 
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)(0))
Next

' Blocks é a variável de cara bloco
```

**OBS:** Aceito respostas em **C#**, **VB** e **Expressões Regulares** (Regex).

Comment: Tem como postar o seu método?

Comment: Qual é a resposta esperada para a entrada `{ "\"}" }`? Ou para a entrada `{ """}" }`? Você está fazendo isso pra fazer parse de JSON ou alguma linguagem de programação?

Comment: Minha própria linguagem @ctgPi

Comment: @qmechanik pronto.

Comment: Não é [**isto**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/o1kojP) o que você quer fazer?

Comment: Se eu entendi direito, não exatamente — considere a entrada `{ echo "{"; }`.

Comment: @qmechanik não exatamente, surge um novo bug mas com o `{`. https://dotnetfiddle.net/DwGiAk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sem saber a especificação da gramática da sua linguagem de programação, fica difícil resolver o caso geral — você deveria considerar ***seriamente*** parar tudo que você está fazendo, pegar um livro de compiladores, um livro de linguagens formais e autômatos, e ***depois*** de ter estudado ambos os tópicos, estudar uma biblioteca tipo [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/), que gera parsers pra C# e Java.

---

Se você absolutamente insiste em escrever um compilador sem estudar a teoria por trás, a primeira coisa que você precisa saber é que a sua linguagem não é regular, mas [livre de contexto](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguagem_livre_de_contexto), e portanto não pode ser processada por expressões regulares (o Google tem [um monte de informação](https://www.google.com/search?q=gram%C3%A1ticas+livres+de+contexto) se você quiser estudar o assunto).

Você vai precisar fazer algo [nessa linha daqui](http://ideone.com/ioWwBv) se você fizer questão de escrever o código na marra (e note que eu não tratei escapes dentro de strings, {} dentro de {}, …).

Comment: Minha linguagem está funcionando perfeitamente, só encontrei esse bug chato, e gostaria ao máximo tentar resolver-lo. Essa linguagem é bastante similar ao C#, separando cada statement pelo caractere `;`, e a string é a clássica manipulada por aspas, porém só quero que o método (algum, qualquer um) separe o caractere `;` dentro de uma string, apenas isso.

Comment: Funcionou, mas teria algum jeito de obter vários blocos de `{ }` em uma `Array`? ideias?

Comment: Pode ser mais específico com um exemplo? Eu acho que era ideal você fazer uma nova pergunta (e botar um link pra essa daqui, se você achar apropriado).

Comment: Não sei se é necessário, seu código funcionou perfeitamente, mas e se eu tiver um arquivo com vários blocos, e quiser obter eles em cada elemento de uma array? possível?

Comment: Você pode usar `.Substring()` pra jogar fora o bloco que a `Parse()` encontrou — a versão que eu tinha começado a escrever aceitava um parâmetro adicional na `Parse()`, `int p`, ao invés de inicializar com `p = 0`; assim você podia especificar o valor de `p` pra procurar um bloco em outra parte da string.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, veja o que tentei ~~> https://dotnetfiddle.net/MNGtBc

Answer (score -3):

Tenta algo parecido ou próximo com essa expressão regular

1 - {[^}]*} 

2 - {(?:[^"']+?|.+?(?:"|').*?(?:"|')?.*?)*?} 
3 - {(.+?)} 
4 - {[\s\S]*?}

se um desses não funcionar, é algo próximo.